# Find array subscript and value which is same

Tags: arrays, data-structures, complexity-theory

I have a sorted array of n elements. The values can be negative or positive.

The specialty of this array is that out of n elements, there is 1 particular element where a[x]=x and the rest of the data does not satisfy the condition.

Is there any better way to find such an 'x' apart from looping the entire array.

Suppose my array is [-2999,-33,0,2,4,67,654]
Here a[4]=4 and the rest does not match such a criterion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the array is already sorted, you can use binary search which is O(lgn) to find the element.

You can also ignore all negative valued elements because an index cannot be negative.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: But I do not know the number right? I need to find the subscript whose value is the same or in other words, value whose subscript is the same. How can Binary Search help me here??

Comment: If I am not wrong, Binary search helps you to find an element in O(log n) whereas I do not know what is the element here that matches the condition.

Comment: Think about it: choose any element with index `i`. If `a[i] = i`, then you hit the element. Otherwise, `a[i] > i` or `a[i] < i`. Figure out in which case you have to search to the left and which case you search to the right. That gives you the algorithm.

Comment: @Zane.. That really did not hit me. My bad. Now I understand how Binary search can be used here.
Out of curiosity, in case the array is not sorted, the only way is to loop through the entire array right?

Comment: @Avinash Correct, if the array is not sorted then the lower bound on finding an element is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this. This is O(N).

```
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
    if(i==array[i]){//do something}
}
```

If the array is sorted in descending order use

```
for(i=MAX-1;i>=0;i11){
    if(i==array[i]){//do something}
}
```

Here MAX is size of array

Comment: This is what I specifically said I do not want.
Refer to the comments from @Zane. You will understand it clearly